# Execute function before changing viewmodel properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have a view in which I'm displaying employee information. In that view i have a checkbox for example: `Recieve Daily Email`. When the user click on that checkbox I need to execute an AJAX function as kind of validation to check if user can change that setting:

```
If result is true:  allow knockout to change the ViewModel Property
If result is false: prevent knockout to change the ViewModel Property
```

I have made a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nx4Xp/) to demonstrate my problem. I supposed my AJAX function 'll `return false`. Try to click on the checkbox then click on the button to check ViewModel value, it 'll be true although it's not checked(because of `return false`).

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the exact behavior that you want the user to see when they check it, but are not allowed, but a good way to something like this is to make the boolean value observable and manually subscribe to it changing.

When you create your `Person` it might be like:

```
function Person(name, receiveMail) {
    this.name = name;
    this.receiveMail = ko.observable(receiveMail);

    this.receiveMail.subscribe(function() {
        //do AJAX here
        setTimeout(function() {
            this.receiveMail(false);
        }.bind(this), 1000);
    }, this);
}
```

So, we make `receiveMail` an observable and subscribe to it changing in the view model. When t changes, you can make your AJAX call and then respond accordingly.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates this along with an error message: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/pMmvf/

Comment: but when you change observable `receiveMail` in `setTimeout` this 'll trigger the `subscribe` function again, Right?

Comment: In the current example it would trigger it a single time. It would be easy to manage this with an additional flag like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/eKdxZ/. If using an AJAX call, you could set the flag to true before making the AJAX request (to prevent potentially multiple requests) and then clear it if the AJAX call fails.